# Finding (and recording) the maximum values of slices of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max

Given a numpy array such as `a = [0, 3, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1, 6, 2]`, is there a simple way to record the maximum value for every 3 values? The length of the array may not be a multiple of 3. In this case, the result should be `b = [3, 4, 3, 6]`.

I thought of something along the lines of

```
b = [max(a[k:k+3]) for k in range(0, len(a), 3)
```

but it doesn't take into account the values after the last multiple of 3 (which it should).

I've also thought of rearranging the numpy array such that it has 3*n rows, and taking the maxima along the proper axis using the numpy module, but, again, I'm not sure how to deal with the values after the last multiple of 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We can use  [`np.ufunc.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) for performing such grouped/intervaled reduction operations. Thus, to get `maximum` values within each interval, we would have -

```
W = 3 # group width
np.maximum.reduceat(a,np.r_[:len(a):W])
```

Sample run -

```
In [166]: a
Out[166]: array([0, 3, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1, 6, 2])

In [167]: W = 3

In [168]: np.maximum.reduceat(a,np.r_[:len(a):W])
Out[168]: array([3, 4, 3, 6])
```

**Approach #2**

Here's another with `slicing` -

```
def max_interval_slice(a, W=3):
    n = len(a)//W
    max0 = a[:n*W].reshape(-1,W).max(1)
    if n*W==len(a):
        return max0
    else:
        return np.r_[max0, np.max(a[n*W:])]
```

Sample runs -

```
# Input array of length NOT multiple of width=3
In [99]: a
Out[99]: array([0, 3, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1, 6, 2])

In [100]: max_interval_slice(a, W=3)
Out[100]: array([3, 4, 3, 6])

# Input array of length multiple of width=3
In [95]: a = a[:9]

In [96]: max_interval_slice(a, W=3)
Out[96]: array([3, 4, 3])
```

Comment: The reduceat solution is perfect. I've found a way to do the slicing one without temp arrays though.

Comment: How do you do the slicing without copying parts of array?

Comment: @ed22 Slicing doesn't do any copying. Not sure which copying are you referring to.

Answer (score 2):

First use **`np.pad`**

```
a = np.pad(a, [0, 1], mode='constant')
```

Then **`reshape`** and **`max`**

```
>>> np.max(a.reshape(-1, 3), axis=1)
array([3, 4, 3, 6])
```

To generalize this, just calculate padding in order to reshape to the desired dimension.

Comment: This is the simplest straightforward solution. +1 for that, no matter how much it irks me that you create a copy

Comment: Yep, that's one negative of this approach. I was trying to do it with some stride tricks but no luck :S

Answer (score 2):

To minimize the amount of reallocation you need to do, you can compute the maxima of all the elements that fit into a multiple of 3, and then the max of the remainder. This solution is not as straightforward, but it does not create unnecessary copies of the data:

```
n = 3  # The group width
prefix, suffix = divmod(a.size, n)
output = np.empty(prefix + bool(suffix))
a[:n * prefix].reshape(-1, n).max(axis=1, out=output[:prefix])
if suffix:
    output[-1] = a[-suffix:].max()
```